# Openlayers - display pacific markers popup using marker id and onclick event

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have the following code which addes 3 markers to the map along with there popup boxes what I want to do is have a list of location at bottom of page and using the id of the marker when click a place in the list it just make that places popup appear on the map.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Open Street Map</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        </style>
        <script src="lib/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var iconSize = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
            var iconOffset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(iconSize.w / 2), -iconSize.h);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("img/fourmarker.png",
                           iconSize, iconOffset);


            var zoom, center, currentPopup, map, lyrMarkers;
            var popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
                "autoSize": true,
                "minSize": new OpenLayers.Size(300, 50),
                "maxSize": new OpenLayers.Size(500, 300),
                "keepInMap": true
            });

            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
            function addMarker(id, lng, lat, info) {
                var pt = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng, lat)
                                       .transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
                                       map.getProjectionObject());
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(lyrMarkers, pt);
                feature.closeBox = true;
                feature.popupClass = popupClass;
                feature.data.popupContentHTML = info ;
                feature.data.overflow = "auto";
                var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(pt, icon.clone());

                var markerClick = function(evt) {
                    if (currentPopup != null && currentPopup.visible()) {
                        currentPopup.hide();
                    }


                    if (this.popup == null) {
                        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
                        map.addPopup(this.popup);
                        this.popup.show();
                    } else {
                        this.popup.toggle();
                    }
                    currentPopup = this.popup;
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
                };
                marker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);
                lyrMarkers.addMarker(marker);
            }

            function initMap() {
                var options = {
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    units: "m",
                    numZoomLevels: 19,
                    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-0.13011, -0.13011, 51.51039, 51.51039)
                };

                map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options);
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan());
                var lyrOsm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                map.addLayer(lyrOsm);
                lyrMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                map.addLayer(lyrMarkers);

                 //add marker on given coordinates
                addMarker('1',-0.12519,51.51112 , '<b>Tescos</b><br/>Covent garden');
                addMarker('2',-0.13264,51.50918 , '<b>Spar</b><br/>Leicester Square');
                addMarker('3', -0.12498,51.50807 , '<b>M & S</b><br/>Embankment');
                center = bounds.getCenterLonLat();
                map.setCenter(center, map.getZoomForExtent(bounds) - 1);
                zoom = map.getZoom();
            }



        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; width:1000px; height:500px;">
        <div id="map"></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

EXTRA INFORMATION

I am going to add a list to bottom of map like so:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">location1</a></li>
<li><a href="">location2</a></li>
<li><a href="">location3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What i want to get working is when the user clicks so location1 alink then that relevent popup box will show and the other will be removed.

How would this be done.

Answer (score 1):

This very fast example (modify addMarker function):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Open Street Map</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
            #list > div { background-color: #aaa; margin-top: 10px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; width:1000px; height:500px;">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="list" style="width:100%; height: 100%"></div>
    </body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var iconSize = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
            var iconOffset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(iconSize.w / 2), -iconSize.h);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("img/fourmarker.png",
                           iconSize, iconOffset);
            var list = document.getElementById('list');


            var zoom, center, currentPopup, map, lyrMarkers;
            var popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
                "autoSize": true,
                "minSize": new OpenLayers.Size(300, 50),
                "maxSize": new OpenLayers.Size(500, 300),
                "keepInMap": true
            });

            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
            function addMarker(id, lng, lat, info) {
                var pt = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng, lat)
                                       .transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
                                       map.getProjectionObject());
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(lyrMarkers, pt);
                feature.closeBox = true;
                feature.popupClass = popupClass;
                feature.data.popupContentHTML = info ;
                feature.data.overflow = "auto";
                var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(pt, icon.clone());

                var markerClick = function(evt) {
                    if (currentPopup != null && currentPopup.visible()) {
                        currentPopup.hide();
                    }


                    if (this.popup == null) {
                        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
                        map.addPopup(this.popup);
                        this.popup.show();
                    } else {
                        this.popup.toggle();
                    }
                    currentPopup = this.popup;
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
                };
                marker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);
                lyrMarkers.addMarker(marker);

                // add items
                var listItem = OpenLayers.Util.createDiv(this.id, null, null, null, 'relative', null);
                listItem.innerHTML = info;
                list.appendChild(listItem);

                var callback = function(e) {
                    marker.events.triggerEvent('mousedown');
                    console.log(marker);
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
                };
                OpenLayers.Event.observe(listItem, "touchend", OpenLayers.Function.bindAsEventListener(callback, this));
                OpenLayers.Event.observe(listItem, "click", OpenLayers.Function.bindAsEventListener(callback, this));

            }

            function initMap() {
                var options = {
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    units: "m",
                    numZoomLevels: 19,
                    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-0.13011, -0.13011, 51.51039, 51.51039)
                };

                map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options);
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan());
                var lyrOsm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                map.addLayer(lyrOsm);
                lyrMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                map.addLayer(lyrMarkers);

                 //add marker on given coordinates
                addMarker('1',-0.12519,51.51112 , '<b>Tescos</b><br/>Covent garden');
                addMarker('2',-0.13264,51.50918 , '<b>Spar</b><br/>Leicester Square');
                addMarker('3', -0.12498,51.50807 , '<b>M & S</b><br/>Embankment');
                center = bounds.getCenterLonLat();
                map.setCenter(center, map.getZoomForExtent(bounds) - 1);
                zoom = map.getZoom();
            }



        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: hi ya I have updated my question with more information if you can possible help

Comment: I can't understand what is the difference? If only in the DOM, then add `<li>` elements    `var listItem= document.createElement('li');` [Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/winsent/vsSYD/)